# Time complexity of functions that call each other

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics

I'm having trouble reasoning about the time complexity of these mutually recursive functions. This was asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640990/calculating-time-complexity-of-functions-when-both-contain-each-other/) but the answer there didn't help me. I tried substituting one of the recurrences in the other but because they are mutually recursive I got stuck. I tried writing out the function calls for x=10 but I'm stuck making sense of that too. How do I go about working through something like this?

```
int foo(int x)
{
  if(x < 1) return 1;
  else return foo(x-1) + bar(x);
}

int bar(int x)
{
  if(x < 2) return 1;
  else return foo(x-1) + bar(x/2);
}
```

Edit: With @quicksort's answer I get S(n) = 2*S(n-1) + S(n/2) - S(n/2-1) and if I try to solve it using Wolfram I'm seeing something different: [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20f(n-1)%2Bf(n%2F2)%20-%20f(n%2F2-1)) . Also, it's not intuitive to me that this is exponential. How does one see that?

Comment: How does that contradict what I said and what does that Wolfram query have to do with anything at all? (just by the way: *don't* use Wolfram Alpha for solving recursive equations of complexity, it's a terrible tool).

Intuition for exponential running time: Function splits in two. Each recursive call splits in two. Each of them further splits in two... See any pattern?

Comment: @quicksort I wasn't questioning your answer, I'm clearly struggling with this. Based on previous questions I'd seen people recommend using Wolfram so that's why I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{S}(n)$ be the running time of `foo` and $\mathcal{T}(n)$ be the running time of `bar`. We have the following system of recursive equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
\mathcal{S}(n) & = & \mathcal{S}(n-1) + \mathcal{T}(n) + \Theta(1)\\
\mathcal{T}(n) & = & \mathcal{S}(n-1) + \mathcal{T}(n/2) + \Theta(1)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

By isolating $\mathcal{T}(n)$ in the first and $\mathcal{S}(n)$ in the second, we obtain:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
\mathcal{S}(n-1) & = & \mathcal{T}(n) - \mathcal{T}(n/2) + \Theta(1)\\
\mathcal{T}(n) & = & \mathcal{S}(n) - \mathcal{S}(n-1) + \Theta(1)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I will now solve for $\mathcal{T}$, with a similar reasoning holding for $\mathcal{S}$. Since:

$$
\mathcal{S}(n-1) = \mathcal{T}(n) - \mathcal{T}(n/2) + \Theta(1)
$$

We also have that:

$$
\mathcal{S}(n) = \mathcal{T}(n+1) - \mathcal{T}((n+1)/2) + \Theta(1)
$$

Therefore the first equation of our original system becomes:

$$
\mathcal{T}(n+1) - \mathcal{T}((n+1)/2) = \mathcal{T}(n) + \mathcal{T}(n) - \mathcal{T}(n/2) + \Theta(1)
$$

Reordering the terms:

$$
\mathcal{T}(n+1) = 2 \mathcal{T}(n) - \mathcal{T}(n/2) + \mathcal{T}((n+1)/2) + \Theta(1)
$$

Since $(n+1)/2$ is either $n/2$ or $n/2+1$, it must be that 
$$ \mathcal{T}((n+1)/2) - \mathcal{T}(n/2) \ge 0$$

which means:

$$
\mathcal{T}(n+1) \ge 2 \mathcal{T}(n) + \Theta(1)
$$

and:

$$
\mathcal{T}(n) \in \Omega(2^n)
$$

We can check the other arrow (i.e. $ \mathcal{T}(n) \in \mathcal{O}(2^n) $) by induction.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get from either of the system of recurrences to a closed form. Is this abnormally complicated or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @MikeSweeney: answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

To help with your intuition, change the code by substituting the code for bar into foo:

```
int foo(int x)
{
  if(x < 1) return 1;
  else if (x < 2) return 2; // foo(0) + bar(1), x = 1
  else return foo(x-1) + foo(x-1) + bar(x/2);
}

int bar(int x)
{
  if(x < 2) return 1;
  else return foo(x-1) + bar(x/2);
}
```

So now it is obvious that T (x) ≥ $Θ(2^x)$, since foo (x) does two recursive calls to foo (x-1). Also makes it obvious that the result is foo (x) ≥ $Θ(2^x)$, and that result can be calculated in linear time.

Comment: I think I understand the first part but what if I wanted to get a tighter bound and account for the call to `bar(x/2)`? Also, I'm not clear what your last sentence regarding the _**result**_ is and where the linear part is coming into the picture.

Comment: Note that $\geq\Theta(f)$ is just $\Omega(f)$.

Comment: The functions return a value - that's the result. You can do the calculation faster. That doesn't change the result. Usually the result is important.

Comment: The result can easily be calculated in O(n) if you replace foo (x-1)+f(x-1) with 2*f(x-1).